datatables.net child isShown returns wrong result
I have a Datatable and want to show extra information in child. I use the same code as here: https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html
But on first click on first column the child is not shown. The source code before clicking:
<tr></tr>

after first click the arrow shows downwards and sourcecode looks like this:
<tr class="dtr-expanded"></tr>

after second click the child is shown (arrow shows to the right) and code looks like this:
<tr class="dt-hasChild selected"></tr>

If I debug the code in js "row.child.isShown()" returns false on first click.
Maybe there is a problem with the select-column?
Additional information: if I don't handle the click method on 'td.dt-control' and let datatables do the work: it works fine, but I want to show different information so I have to make use of this functionality.
thx in advance
©a-x-i

Not sure what you mean by "the source code" - I guess you mean the DOM when inspecting via developer tools.  If that's the case, then the table on the page you linked doesn't appear to work that way and just toggles dt-hasChild.  There's no dtr-expanded on that page (that I could find using your provided steps).

"if I don't handle click .. and let datatables do the work" - so are you using that code or your own code that you've not provided in the question?

yes I mean DOM, sorry for that.
dtr-expanded: https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/3.0.0/ --> I have nothing added in code.
The code is nearly the same as in the datatables.net sample. So, if I don't add an event listener collaps/expand is working.

the problem seems to be the responsive: true, on creating the table. If I remove this attribute, I get nearly the behavior I want.
